# Java public hashtables

Tags: java, hashtable

So I want to be able to have a public hashtable (kind of like how you would have a public String or int etc etc field). How would I go about doing that? I've tried something like this:

```
public class Home {
    public static Hashtable<String, Double> test = new Hashtable<String, Double>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test.put("A", 1.2);
        test.put("B", 1.3);
        test.put("C", 1.4);

        System.out.println(test.get("A");
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to access the Hashtable and its information in another class though. What would be the method to go about doing that? Is what I have sufficient? Thanks.

Comment: Home.test should work

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Home.test.put("A", 1.2);
        Home.test.put("B", 1.3);
        Home.test.put("C", 1.4);

        System.out.println(Home.test.get("A");
    }
```

Comment: thanks, there were other errors too but this certainly helped

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the `Map` as `Home.test`

However, you won't have added any of the initial values. You'll need a separate method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The map can be reached with `Home.test` as in `Home.test.put("A", 1.2)` but you should use [encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm). Note that the static keyword means all instances of the class share the same map, if you want it to be unique per instance you must remove the `static` keyword.

Declare the Map (it is better to use the interface) as private and provide getter/setter.

```
public class ClassWithTheTable{

    private static Map<String, Double> table = new Hashtable<String,Double)>();

    public Map<String, Double> getTable(){
      return table;
    }

    public void setTable(Map<String,Double> table){
      this.table = table;
    }
    //Rest of code ommited.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If several threads access to the variable, may you want to use:

```
public static final Map<String, Double> test = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

You can access from another class with

```
double value = Home.test.get("A");
```